# Bash: more than one command line substitution

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-arguments

```
$touch file{1,2}
$echo "file1" >>  file1
$^1^2
=>echo "file2">>file1
```

But I wanted it to be

```
echo "file2">>file2
```

How to do more than one substitution ?

Comment: The same question has been posted at http://superuser.com/questions/651535/bash-more-than-one-command-line-substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!!:gs/1/2
```

should do it.  `^1^2` is a shortcut for `!!:s/1/2`, and you just need to supply the `g` flag.

Comment: @VihaanVerma Try ** as suggested**.  Say `!!:gs/1/2` or `!!:as/1/2`.